# Cython: Convert unicode string to wchar array

Tags: python, unicode, cython, python-2.6

I am working on using Cython to interface with an external C API that accepts unicode strings in the UCS2 format (array of wchar).  (I understand the limitations of UCS2 vis-a-vis UTF-16, but it's a third-party API.)

- **Cython Version**: 0.15.1
- **Python Version**: 2.6 (Narrow unicode build)
- **OS**: FreeBSD

The Cython user guide deals extensively with converting unicode to byte strings, but I couldn't figure out how to convert to a 16-bit array.  I realize I first need to encode to UTF-16 (and I assume for now that code-points beyond the BMP don't occur).  What do I do next?  Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is very possible on **Python 3**, and a solution is such:

```
# cython: language_level=3

from libc.stddef cimport wchar_t

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    wchar_t* PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(object, Py_ssize_t *)

cdef extern from "wchar.h":
    int wprintf(const wchar_t *, ...)

my_string = u"Foobar\n"
cdef Py_ssize_t length
cdef wchar_t *my_wchars = PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(my_string, &length)

wprintf(my_wchars)
print("Length:", <long>length)
print("Null End:", my_wchars[7] == 0)
```

A less good Python 2 method follows, but it might be dealing in undefined or broken behaviours, so I'd not trust it too easily:

```
# cython: language_level=2

from cpython.ref cimport PyObject
from libc.stddef cimport wchar_t
from libc.stdio  cimport fflush, stdout
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    ctypedef PyObject PyUnicodeObject
    Py_ssize_t PyUnicode_AsWideChar(PyUnicodeObject *o, wchar_t *w, Py_ssize_t size)

my_string = u"Foobar\n"
cdef Py_ssize_t length = len(my_string.encode("UTF-16")) // 2 # cheating
cdef wchar_t *my_wchars = <wchar_t *>malloc(length * sizeof(wchar_t))
cdef Py_ssize_t number_written = PyUnicode_AsWideChar(<PyUnicodeObject *>my_string, my_wchars, length)

# wprintf breaks things for some reason
print [my_wchars[i] for i in range(length)]
print "Length:", <long>length
print "Number Written:", <long>number_written
print "Null End:", my_wchars[7] == 0

free(my_wchars)
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert string to wchar_t in one line?

Comment: Is `PyUnicode_AsWideCharString` not terse enough for you?

Comment: I want to convert list of python strings into array of c wchars, but do not understand, how to apply `PyUnicode_AsWideCharString`. I will appreciate if you help me to understand this. I also asked a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185968/how-to-convert-python-list-of-strings-into-c-array-of-wchar-t