# How to convert Python list of strings into C array of wchar_t?

Tags: c, python-3.x, cython, wchar-t

The source code in C looks like:

```c
typedef wchar_t            char_t;
typedef const char_t*  const_string_t;
static const_string_t g_symbols[] = { {L"IBM"}, {L"MSFT"}, {L"YHOO"}, {L"C"} };
...
some_c_func(g_symbols)
...
```

some_c_func is declared somewhere earlier with something like:

```c
int some_c_func(const_string_t* symbols)
```

It is important that g_symbols is passed to some_c_func function, so I have to write wrapper over it, that should look somehow like:

```py
ctypedef wchar_t char_t
ctypedef const char_t*  const_string_t

def some_py_func(py_list=['a', 'b', 'c']):
    g_symbols = ... # some transformation from py_list to g_symbols
    some_c_func(g_symbols)
    print('Done!')
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: This is not a valid strategy to delete a question and to repost it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865245/how-to-convert-array-of-chars-from-python-to-c-in-cython. Given that in the old version you was given feedback what to improve in the question to make it understandable and even got an educated guess by DavidW for a possible reason for your problem,  we have to start from the scratch now. You are supposed to improve your question and not to discard the given feedback.

Comment: I vote to close this question as too broad, because it consist of multiple subquestions: If you don't know how to get/pass an `wchar_t` from unicode-objectresearch it on SO/enywhere else and ask a **specific**  and **precise** question(see also [mcve] ) about what stays unclear. If you don't know what `wchar_t**` is and how to handle it/to populate it with values - use the same approach as above: do research and ask a **specific** question. If you don't know how to manage memory - ask specific question about it (after having done research).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidW, but I found, I think, simplier solution:

```py
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Free

def some_py_func(py_list=['a', 'b', 'c']):
    cdef int number = len(symbols)  # get c int of elements
    cdef int idx # for faster loops

    # create array with dynamic memory allocation
    cdef const_string_t *g_symbols = <const_string_t *> PyMem_Malloc(number * sizeof(const_string_t))

    # create array with cycle
    for idx, sym in enumerate(py_list):
        g_symbols[idx] = PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(sym, NULL)

    # call c function
    some_c_func(g_symbols)

    # free memory
    for idx in range(number):
        PyMem_Free(g_symbols[idx])
    PyMem_Free(g_symbols)
    print('Done!')
```

Comment: You've got a memory leak. You free `g_symbols` but not any of the strings in it

Comment: @DavidW could you, please, modify my code to get rid of this problem? Should I add a loop at the end and free iteratively?

Comment: Yes - just before `PyMem_Free(g_symbols)` you need a loop of `PyMem_Free(g_symbols[idx])`

Comment: @DavidW is it ok now?

Comment: Yes - that looks fine

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a `wchar*` from a unicode object is probably [`PyUnicode_AsWideCharString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsWideCharString). Cython doesn't provide a definition so you need to do a suitable `cdef extern` yourself:

```
 from libc.stddef cimport wchar_t
 from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Free

 cdef extern from "Python.h":
     wchat_t* PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(object, Py_ssize_t*) except NULL

 def f(string):
     cdef wchar_t* c_string = PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(string, NULL)
     # use the string
     PyMem_Free(<void*>c_string) # you must free it after use
```

Read the documentation to see if you should use the "size" argument.

To allocate space for an array of `wchar_t*` you should use `malloc` or `calloc`. You should `free` this space when you're done with it. You need to cast from `malloc`

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef wchar_t** strings = <wchar_t**>malloc(sizeof(wchar_t*)*length)
# do something
free(<void*>strings)
```

A common pattern from ensuring memory is cleaned up to use try and finally:

```
def some_py_func(py_list):
    g_symbols = malloc(...)
    try:
        # loop through py_list getting wchar_t*
        # call your C function 
    finally:
        # loop through g_symbols calling PyMem_Free
        free(g_symbols)
```

You need to be careful that you only call `PyMem_Free` on valid (or `NULL`) pointers in the event of an exception. Remember that memory from `malloc` may be filled with arbitrary values that it isn't safe to pass to `PyMem_Free`.

Comment: it is probably safer/easier to allocate memory with `calloc` - this way `strings` are filled with `NULL`s and it is easier to decide whether `PyMem_Free` should be called.